# Get response Bluetooth Low Energy device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an Android app than can transmit commands to a 4.0 Bluetooth serial device. I am suppose to get a response from the device. I was able to connect to the device and send the command, but how can I get this response? I have tried with a BluetoothGattServerCallback but it doesn`t work. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Handler handler;
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 12000;
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;

private LinearLayout pairedDevicesList;
private LinearLayout availableDevicesList;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private BluetoothGatt gatt;
private List<BluetoothGattService> services;
private BluetoothGattServer gattServer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pairedDevicesList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
    availableDevicesList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.available_devices);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    handler = new Handler();

    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    gattServer = bluetoothManager.openGattServer(this, new BluetoothGattServerCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWriteRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean preparedWrite, boolean responseNeeded, int offset, byte[] value) {
            super.onCharacteristicWriteRequest(device, requestId, characteristic, preparedWrite, responseNeeded, offset, value);
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onCharacteristicWriteRequest");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNotificationSent(BluetoothDevice device, int status) {
            super.onNotificationSent(device, status);
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onNotificationSent");
        }
    });
    btAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    final BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    pairedDevicesList.removeAllViews();

    final Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    if (pairedDevices != null) {
        for (final BluetoothDevice pairedDevice : pairedDevices) {
            addListItem(pairedDevicesList, pairedDevice);
        }
    }

    scanLeDevice(true);

    super.onResume();
}

private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);
        btAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "scanning bluetooth LE devices");
    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
    }
}

// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        addListItem(availableDevicesList, device);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

@Override
public void onPause() {
    scanLeDevice(false);

    super.onPause();
}

private void addListItem(final LinearLayout list, final BluetoothDevice device) {
    //only add devices with the right name
    if (device == null ||
            device.getName() == null ||
            //name of prototype: RNDEF8
            !device.getName().startsWith("RND")) {

        return;
    }

    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "device: " + device.getName());

    final View item = getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.li_bluetooth_device, list, false);
    ((TextView)item.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(device.getName());
    item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            gatt = device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, gattCallback);
        }
    });
    list.addView(item, 0);
}

private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "Status: " + status);
        switch (newState) {
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                Log.i("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                gatt.discoverServices();
                break;
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                break;
            default:
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        services = gatt.getServices();
        Log.i("onServicesDiscovered", services.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic
                                             ch, int status) {
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), ch.getPermissions() + "");
        gatt.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    }
};


private static final UUID Read_UUID = UUID.fromString("00035b03-58e6-07dd-021a-08123a000300");
public void sendCommand(final byte[] value) {
    BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(Read_UUID);
    gattServer.addService(service);
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00035b03-58e6-07dd-021a-08123a000301"));
    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    characteristic.setValue(value);
    gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "" +  gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic));
}

public void sendSU(View view) {
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "clicked su");
    sendCommand("\r".getBytes());
}

public void sendSL(View view) {
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "clicked sl");
    sendCommand("SL".getBytes());
}

public void sendSP(View view) {
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "clicked sp");
    sendCommand("SP".getBytes());
}
}
```

Thanks!